# Question about adding controls to a winform

Tags: winforms

In .NET Winforms, if I have some code which does something such as execute a stored proc against a SQL Server but I do not know how many parameters there are, can I add more controls to the form with the controls appearing straight away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking here, but you can always add controls to a form dynamically.  So, for example, if your code can determine that a stored procedure requires three string parameters, you could dynamically add three text boxes (plus three labels) to your form to allow users to enter values for these three parameters.

Comment: Yea that's what I am as asking. I was just wondering if the updated controls show up immediately. Something to try.